# Formulate a rigorous answer to why we need to store the return adress of a function

Tags: c, stack

While preparing for an exam in C-programming I encountered the following question.

> Both local variables and a function’s return address are stored in a so
>   called call frame (or activation record).  Why do we need to store the
>   return address of a function and in which of the four memory segments
>   are the call frames stored?

In my head, I answered the question in the following way:

I have learned that the stack stores return adresses, therefor the call frame which stores return adresses is the stack. We need to store the return adresses of a function because otherwise, when executing a function the program would not know where to go after the function is executed.

I am not satisfied with my answer, because I feel that I lack a "programming" language. How can I improve the answer? For example there might be programming terms that I can add to the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason.

Comment: You understand the issue well enough,. why would you need a more formal answer?

Comment: I feelt that I didnt explain it well enough, for example if it was an exam question. @MartinJames

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to store the return address to go back to the calling function. On some architectures it is stored on the stack, on some architectures it is stored in a register.

Comment: Functions can be nested arbitrarily deep. Are there really CPUs that have that many registers?

Comment: In these cases, the return address to the caller is stored in a register (the link register) but the caller is expected to have saved its own return address (the link register) in the stack.

Comment: @RadLexus For any given function anywhere in the call stack, which is about to call another function, the compiler may reason: "My calling convention says that parameter 1 can be passed through register x. Is register x free? If so, great, store the parameter there. If not, temporarily stack the contents of register x, write the parameter to the register, call the function, then restore the register." How this is done in practice depends on a lot of things: the calling convention specified by the ABI, as well as how the compiler optimizes code.